# After creating many TextViews and giving them IDs, I am trying to open an activity with their information. How do I do that?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

So I can successfully create an android Text View using java and set it a value and an ID. But my problem is that after I create them and gave them values and id, I have no control over them. After clicking on them, I want the new page to have the data that was stored in that Text View.

Here is how I created and set value and ID to my Text Views:

```
                             textView = new TextView(SellActivity.this);

                            // put the data in the text view
                            textView.setText(data);


                            // give it an id
                            textView.setId(Integer.parseInt(getStrID));


                            //place it nicely under one another
                            textView.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);

                            // if clicked any of the textviews, open the offer page
                            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    //setGetStrID(getStrID);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SellActivity.this, OfferActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                            // add the text view to our layout
                            linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: So whats your problem, you dont know how to pass data between activities? You want OfferActivity to have the content of the textview , right?

Comment: You'll have to manually send the data using Bundle,so that the other activity receives your data and then the other activity will have a layout,where you'll have to create a textview and set the text of the textview ,each activity has a different layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass the data to the new intent,

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(SellActivity.this, OfferActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("TextViewContent", textView.getText());
             startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

Then in `onCreate` function of `OfferActivity.java`,

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("TextViewContent");
```

Now the string s will contain the value of your textView.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data in the intent when you are opening a new activity

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                //setGetStrID(getStrID);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SellActivity.this, OfferActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("mydata", textView.getText());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
```

In the oncreate of OfferActivity receive this data as string

```
String mydata = intent.getStringExtra("mydata");
```